# Apach2 mod_ruid2 and RDocumentChRoot -- Can't Connect to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache2, chroot

In Apache2 virtualhost, I've got mod_ruid2 working as I want using RMode stat.  I added RDocumentChRoot to chroot the process to the website folder and an unwanted side-effect is that PHP can't connect to the MySQL database.  I googled for help and couldn't find anything.

Can anyone throw me some rope?

Comment: Elaborate on your setup. Actual directives and a path layout overview might make this an answerable question. PS: find out where the mysql socket thingy lives.

Comment: "PS: find out where the mysql socket thingy lives"   LOL  I'm just about as clueless as that statement sounds. LOL  I know that Linux devices are treated as part of the file system.  Are sockets treated the same way?

Comment: For completeness to my question about sockets, I'm pretty sure "real sockets" are not treated as regular files, but mysqld and some other applications will sometimes create "socket files" (usually in the form *.sock) which are just pipes to redirect to a real socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mario for mentioning the "mysql socket thingy".  After some searching around, I found out MySQLD uses a file called mysqld.sock as an optional way to receive connections.  Running 'locate *.sock' on your system will show you .sock files.  dkim-filter also uses a .sock file.  According to another website I read, socket files are FIFO files created by applications and they do nothing more than act as a redirectional pipe to allow applications to communicate with each other without having to go through other socket configuration stuff.

In the case I asked about, a chrooted php process can't access the .sock file since its outside the chroot.  Fortunately, I deduced that PHP uses the .sock file because of a connection variable.  In WordPress, the default configuration uses 'localhost'.  A  'localhost' specification in PHP will cause PHP to look for the .sock file instead of doing a network connection.  Changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' fixed the problem gracefully.  No hardlinks or other workarounds were needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a comment in [this PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42977) which you might find useful.

As far as I read PHP source, it's not possible to change the behaviour from run-time. You must modify the source for it to work through TCP.

If anyone think I'm wrong, please tell us how to bypass this behaviour from run-time configuration :D